# Android Studio cannot build correctly with Expo

Tags: react-native, kotlin, android-studio, expo

I'm new to mobile app development and I'm wanting to make an app with native modules in expo, and I saw that to code better they used Android Studio for Kotlin.

I would like to be able to use Android Studio to have autocompletion and the rest of the features that make it more comfortable for me to work.

PROBLEM: My problem is two things:

1 – I don't know which of the two android folders I should open with Android Studio XD

2 - In case it is the one found inside the examples folder, android throws me the error.

[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfTIS.png)

In case that is not the Android folder to open, when you open the other one you get an error with expo-modules-core.

What should I do to fix it? I was searching a lot on the internet and I didn't find much, maybe I couldn't understand the solutions I saw well. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you very much!

I tried updating jdk11 to jdk21, using expo doctor and nothing. I hope to be able to use the android studio IDE normally to be able to work with native applications on android with expo and react native

Comment: So you are trying to use Kotlin to write React Native using Expo ?